# url rewrite strip slashes unless a hashbang precedes

Tags: ruby, url-rewriting, rack

I'm using rack-rewrite to add a url rewrite rule that will strip slashes, but I only want it to do it if there isn't a hashbang following the slash.

I tried the following regex, but it rewrites anyway, even if there is a `#!` after the `/`:

```
^/(?!#!.*)(.*)/$

# The rule
r301 %r{^/(?!#!.*)(.*)/$}, '/$1'
```

As an example, if the url would be `tada/`, it should rewrite to `tada`, but if it were `tada/#!WHATEVER_STRINGS_HERE` it should not enforce the rule. What is my regex missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be missing that URL fragments (a `#` and everything following it) are never submitted to the server at all. When the browser is asked to visit the URL `/foo/bar#baz`, it will only request `/foo/bar` from the server and handle the `#baz` locally inside the retrieved document.

Comment: Damn it, of course the fragments are not submitted. I'm an idiot :) Thanks